# PCA Eigenface is wrong and staticy and I dont know what Im doing wrong

Tags: machine-learning, face-recognition, eigenvector

I am trying to generate eigenfaces using principle component analysis and have gone through the following steps to do so. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

- data matrix: (N, width * height)
- normalized matrix: data matrix - mean vector
- covariance matrix: (data matrix).T @ (data matrix) *results in matrix of shape (width * height, width * height)
- find eigen vectors of covariance matrix using np.linalg.eig function
- rescale the eigen vector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue to fit within 0 and 255
- reshape the eigen vector to (width, height)
- display the eigen vector.

Code is below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

dataset_size = 500
width = 178
height = 218

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])

img = mpimg.imread('blah/000005.jpg')
gray = np.zeros((218, 178))
gray_base = rgb2gray(img)

data_matrix = np.zeros((dataset_size, int((width+2) * (height+2) / 4)))
for i in range(1, dataset_size):
    if(i < 10):
        img = mpimg.imread('blah/00000' + str(i) + '.jpg')
    elif(i < 100):
        img = mpimg.imread('blah/0000' + str(i) + '.jpg')
    else:
        img = mpimg.imread('blah/000' + str(i) + '.jpg')
    temp_blah = rgb2gray(img)
    temp_blah = np.pad(temp_blah, 1, mode='constant')
    grayscale = temp_blah.reshape((-1,2,temp_blah.shape[-1])).max(1)
    grayscale = grayscale.reshape((grayscale.shape[0], 2, int(grayscale.size/(grayscale.shape[0] * 2))), order='F').max(1)
    # plt.imshow(grayscale, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin=0, vmax=255)
    # plt.show()
    data_matrix[i, :] = grayscale.reshape((1,data_matrix.shape[1]))

print("normalizing...")
avg = np.sum(data_matrix, axis=0) / dataset_size
normalized = data_matrix - avg
print("normalized | shape: " + str(normalized.shape))
print("calculating covariance matrix...")
cov = (normalized.T @ normalized)
print("finding eigenfaces")
w, v = np.linalg.eig(cov)
eigenface = np.real(v[:,w.size - 1])
print(v)
print("------------------")
print(w)
print("------------------")

# final = normalized @ v[:,w.size-1]
# print(final.shape)
print(eigenface)
print("------------------")
eigenface = np.ceil(np.interp(eigenface, (eigenface.min(), eigenface.max()), (0, 255)))
print(eigenface)
temp = np.reshape(eigenface, (int((height + 2)/2), int((width+2)/2)))
plt.imshow(temp, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

This is my eigenface:
[image]

I am relatively new to machine learning so thank you for your assistance. I am trying to learn hands on by googling and experimenting with stuff but I am now at a road block

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having this problem, I realized the issue was a two part: make sure after you calculate your eigenvectors, you are using the columns instead of the rows. In my case v[:,i] was the ith eigenvector. Additionally, make sure you are looking at eigenvectors with corresponding high eigenvalues. I was looking at the one with the smallest eigenvalue leading to that image above. Have fun coding!